# I am using PH photo library to get all the photos and videos

Tags: objective-c, phphotolibrary

i am saving all photos to uicollectionview. but it is saving in uiimageview. i need to show a play button when the file is video type.
is there any way to find the type of the media while fetching ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every[`PHAsset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/PHAsset) has a property **mediaType** which is `PHAssetMediaType`. It shows what type it is: Image, Video, Audio or eventually Unknown.
There is also a **mediaSubtypes** property for some more specific info about the asset (high frame rate video, time-lapse video and so on).

So basically when you spread out the results in your collection view you display an image as a thumbnail but when you check the **mediaType** and you see it's a video you can decide how to deal with it - either prepare a player or present an other view/view controller to play that video.

Hope it helps for a start as I don't know how you've structured your fetching from the Photos library.

Comment: Similar question with a LARGE BOUNTY http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791151/100-bounty-actually-get-the-filename-of-image-saved-to-photos-album-2017-ios10

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PHFetchResult` to get all `PHAsset`,change [PHAssetMediaType](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phassetmediatype?language=objc) you can get different result.

**Here are get all videos sample codes:**

```
PHFetchResult *results = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeVideo options:nil];
NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:results.count];

[results enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    [temp addObject:obj];
}];
```